# Google App Engine deploy error: Error scanning entry module-info.class

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing an application and I would like to deploy in Google app engine.
I'm using Eclipse with google cloud plug in.
I'm using JDK 1.8.
When I deploy the application I receive this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class
>   from jar
>   file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar